# In Navigation Drawer Activity should I use activity or fragment on menu?

Tags: android, android-drawer

When item on drawer is clicked on should I make it call fragment or activity?

Comment: I know it's closed as primarily opinion-based, but a good answer could help people understand pros and cons of the above approach. I want to try Activity instead of a fragment but don't know if it would effect the performance or anything else..

Comment: While fragment generally is the proper way to go, I found on my latest project I would prefer to use Activities. My Activities get quite complex with their own fragment features appearing from them. Additionally I like repeating a navigation menu on many screens. To keep from repeating too much code, I create a Base Activity with a Navigation Drawer to repeat on various pages.

Answer (score 2):

When using navigation drawer, you should use fragments. These fragments are loaded and displayed on your main activity (where you created your navigation view). So every time you click an item on the drawer it replaces the current fragment with the fragment associated with that menu item, the activity does not change.

Comment: Is there a disadvantage of using Activity?

Comment: Remember a fragment is housed by an activity .If you use an activity as an item in the drawer, when the activity is called it will replace the current activity(main activity) that contains your navigation drawer. This means that you will lose your drawer. Except if you decide to create the drawer on every activity you open. Whereas a fragment will just replace a portion of the activity with the new UI you want to show.

Comment: you can create a base activity that implements the drawer, then extend all activities from base activity to have it. you don't need to create a drawer for every activity.

Answer (score 1):

in Drawer you can use Activity or Fragment.
But, Fragment is Loaded with in Same Layout. So, Fragment looks Good.